# Помогите объяснить последовательность цикла, почему for написан 4 раза?

Tags: массивы, java

```
int i , j , k = 0;
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
  for(j=0; j<5; j++) {
    twoD[i][j] = k;
    k++;
  }
  for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for(j=0; j <5; j++)
      System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
    System.out.println ();
  }
}
}
```

На экран выдает

```
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первые два цикла заполняют двумерный массив. Вторые два выводят его содержимое.